# How do I use part of a text form input to add and make it go to an url?

Tags: javascript, forms, window.location

The title might not be clear, but I'll explain it here. I'm a total newbie and I have almost no knowlege in JS, so please be clear.

My main code is here:

```
function goTo()
{
    var url = "http://myurl.com/";
    var name = document.forms[0].name.value;
    window.location = url+name;
    return false;
}
```

The code uses a set url and a form value, then if I press the send button, it jumps to the preset url + the form value.
But what I want, is to get just the last part of the input, so for example, this is my input:

```
http://lolsite.com/testing/files/HAfg76SDA
```

And I want the code to get the part of the input after the "/", so the finished product would be "HAfg76SDA". Now I want to snip this product at the end of my preset url, so when I press the submit button, it goes to:

```
http://myurl.com/HAfg76SDA
```

I would like to know if is this even possible, and if it is, I would nedd a code i could use straight away. Btw. I tried to use

```
function goTo()
{
    var url = "http://myurl.com/";
    var name = document.forms[0].name.value.(lastIndexOf("/")+1);
    window.location = url+name;
    return false;
}
```

but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: `document.forms[0].name` will return the name attribute of the form. Are you sure that is what you want? Moreover, `value.(lastIndexOf("/")+1)` itself seems to be wrong.

Comment: I actually got the code from the internet, and yes, the `document.forms[0].name` logically would use the form name but it used the form content in a somewhat interesting way. I know it seems to be wrong, but in the code it was it worked perfectly, and I actually only needed a way to attach that `value.(lastIndexOf("/")+1)` to the code itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function goTo()
{
    var url = "http://myurl.com/";
    var name = document.forms[0].name.value;
    window.location = url+name.substr(name.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
    return false;
}
```